# Equivalent c# code to get datetime format

Tags: c#, datetime

We have `js` code which converts `datetime` to specific format which is as below:

```
var dob=new Date("01/16/1989")
var ms=(dob.getTime()/1000-dob.getTimeZoneOffset()*60)
```

**output in ms - 600912000**

It returns a date time with some `milliseconds format`. Couldn't quite understand what actually it does. I tried to replicate the same in `c#`, but was getting

> Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'

Here is what I tried:

```
private static string GetFormatted(DateTime date)
{
    var time = Convert.ToInt32(date.ToUniversalTime())/1000;
    var timezoneoffset = Convert.ToInt32(TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow)) * 60;
    return Convert.ToString(time - timezoneoffset);
}
```

What part should I change in above code to get the same result as in `js`?

Comment: What will `ms` exactly as a result?

Comment: Could you provide a clear example of input and output you expect to see?

Comment: And what should the number represent? Millseconds since a specific date?

Comment: @Ralf.. I wish I could have told you if I understood what `js` was doing.. :(

Comment: come on.. Why downvotes?? I've shown what I've tried.. I was doing further investigation on this.. But by then I got answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JS `getTime` returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 . So / 1000 gives the seconds. Finally `getTimeZoneOffset` gives the difference with UTC in minutes, but when converting to C#, when both source and comparison date have the same timezone, the conversion could be skipped and I think the following would suffice:

```
date.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: Perfect... Thanks much.. :)